# Swift Combine Pipeline to compare draft model

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a VielModel in SwiftUI handling my person model. To be able to store draft persons in the editor in the View(s), I have two objects:

```
@Published var person: Person
@Published var draftPerson: Person
```

In the UI, I am only changing the draftPersons until the user clicks on "Save", which stores the draftPerson as the person. In the onAppear method of the editor, I reset the draftPerson to the person.

Now I want to disable the "Save" button of the Editor and therefor introduced a bool "modified" in the VM. Using a pipeline, I want to set the modified to true, if and as long as the draftPerson is not equal to person, by doing the following:

```
    $draftPerson.map { draftPerson in
        return draftPerson != self.person
    }
    .assign(to: \.modified, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

It looks like it is working on first glance, but if I change something in a textField, the value of modified is only set to true after the second change in the field. Vice versa, if I delete the typed values, it is only set back to false after I delete one more character as were originally there.

Question 1:
Is there another "best practice" to handle changes in draft objects and deactivating the "Save" button in SwiftUI?

Question 2:
Why is the pipeline "one change behind"?

Thanks a lot for your input.

**Edit**: I created a separate part of the App focusing only on the pipeline and realized that it is indeed working as intended if I remove my other pipelines. I have to check now in detail. Nevertheless, I will stick with my first question:
Is there anything I can do better?

Please find the code [here on Github](https://gist.github.com/brenner-tobias/0dcf340342e9142d8538458c5d945e9f)

Comment: This looks clear. I take it that the goal is (more or less) to disable Save if they are the same and enable Save if they are different because the user changed the value of the draft person text field, yes? How is the text field "hooked" to `draftPerson`?

Comment: Exactly, thanks for the reply. The Textfeld is bound to the var „name“ in the struct „Person“. The code in the view is:

Comment: TextField("Name", text: $personViewModel.draftPerson.name)

Comment: Can you show how the view model fits into the actual view? How is it being held? It really would help if you would _show_ your code instead of talking _about_ it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @matt, I changed the initial question accordingly. It seems to work now in the reduced version, so if there is anything else you would like to point out in my code, please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare another `@Published` property and combine the two person and draftPerson publishers and publish whether they are the same, like this:

```
@Published var person: Person
@Published var draftPerson: Person
@Published var saveDisabled: Bool = true

public init() {
    
    // all init code
    
    Publishers.CombineLatest($person, $draftPerson)
        .map { $0 == $1 }
        .assign(to: &$saveDisabled)
    
}
```

But essentially it is not needed and a computed property will do the same job:

```
var saveDisabled: Bool {
    person == draftPerson
}
```

Because both person and draftPerson are marked `@Published` each time one of them changes the `View` will be notified of the change so it will also pick new value of saveDisabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I did (sorry for not adding the property in my initial post), but you can see the code here: https://gist.github.com/brenner-tobias/0dcf340342e9142d8538458c5d945e9f

Comment: The idea / simplification with a computed var is good though, I will give that a try